# What is the difference between init block and constructor in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor, initialization-block

I have started learning Kotlin. I would like to know the difference between `init` block and `constructor`.
What is the difference between this and how we can use this to improve?

```
class Person constructor(var name: String, var age: Int) {
    var profession: String = "test"

    init {
        println("Test")
     }    
}
```

Comment: Do check this : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: checkout this  [init-blocks kotlin vs Java](https://chetangupta.net/init-blocks/) I explained what is init block and how its invoked order plus how it's different from Java's init block

Answer (score 244, accepted):

The **init** block will execute immediately after the primary constructor. Initializer blocks effectively become part of the primary constructor.

The **constructor** is the secondary constructor. Delegation to the primary constructor happens as the first statement of a secondary constructor, so the code in all initializer blocks is executed before the secondary constructor body.

**Example**

```
class Sample(private var s : String) {
    init {
        s += "B"
    }
    constructor(t: String, u: String) : this(t) {
        this.s += u
    }
}
```

Think you initialized the Sample class with

```
Sample("T","U")
```

You will get a string response at variable **s** as `"TBU"`.

Value `"T"` is assigned to **s** from the **primary constructor** of **Sample** class.
Then immediately the **init** block starts to execute; it will add `"B"` to the **s** variable.
Next it is the **secondary constructor** turn; now `"U"` is added to the **s** variable to become `"TBU"`.

Answer (score 46):

Since,

> The primary constructor cannot contain any code.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

the `init{..}` blocks allow adding code to the primary constructor.

Comment: Short and sweet ans.

Answer (score 22):

A class in Kotlin class a primary constructor (the one after a class name) which does not contain code, it is only able to initialize properties (e.g. `class X(var prop: String)`).

The `init{..}` block in the place, <strike>where you can put more code that will run *after* properties are initialized</strike>:

> initializer blocks are executed in the same order as they appear in the class body, interleaved with the property initializers

More about that is in  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors

Here is an example:

```
class X(var b: String) {
  val a = print("a")

  init {
    print("b")
  }

  constructor() : this("aaa") {
    print("c")
  }
}


X()
```

When called it prints `abc`. Thus the `init{..}` in invoked *after* primary constructor but before a secondary one.

Comment: So, if we have a secondary constructor, init block will call the first or secondary constructor? We can not initialize values in primary constructor. right?

Comment: Thanks, I've added an example in the answer

Comment: "where you can put more code that will run _after_ properties are initialized" That's not correct. Actually "initializer blocks are executed in the same order as they appear in the class body, _interleaved_ with the property initializers". To see the difference, move `val a` after the `init` block.

Comment: what happens to the `this("aaa")` after the secondary constructor's initializer is called. why doesn't `a = "aaa" `?

Comment: @KyleAngeloGonzales `a` doesn't equal `"aaa"` because `this("aaa")` is initializing the `b` variable of `class X`, not the `a` variable. If given `val x = X()`, `x.b` would equal `"aaa"`, and `x.a` would be equal to the return value of the `print()` function, which is just `Unit`. Poor choice of variable names by the answerer.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the Kotlin docs:

> The primary constructor **cannot** contain **any code**. Initialization code can be placed in **initializer blocks**, which are prefixed with the `init` keyword.

> During an instance initialization, the **initializer blocks** are executed in the **same order** as they appear in the **class body**, interleaved with the property initializers: ...

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors